# Uncheck all (auto generated) checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

- I have a page with 10-25 checkboxes, for a User to choose from.
- The checkbox Name and Value are unique to every User/choice and is handled appropriately in the backend.
- So, without relying on those two properties, is it possible to create a simple "Uncheck all" button that will uncheck all the checked checkboxes?

I guess it's OK to use the ID attribute, I can add one to the template.

The page is built with HTML and JQuery 2.0.3

Here is a sample checkbox:

`<input type="checkbox" name="10953734" value="82S1X93">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a small jQuery to solve your issue.

```
 $("input[name='10953734']").prop("checked", false);
```

or if you want all check box inside a container to be unchecked

```
 $("#containerID input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", false);
```

Comment: The first one is unique to one checkbox. I need to have all checkboxes accounted for, without relying on the name/value attributes. I will try your second piece of code and report back momentarily.

Comment: I added a code that will allow you to group your check boxes inside a container so you can have a scope where all checkboxes inside it will be unchecked.

Comment: @EricMuller, please dont forget to mark this as an answer if it solved your problem :) thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to them:

```
$("input.myClass").prop("checked", false);
```

Comment: The OP does not include a class on his inputs.

Comment: Correct. He did mention he could add an ID to them though, so adding a class seems like similar effort. This also allows for more efficient selection across multiple forms.

Comment: But why do it? if you can just use the parent and child selector?

Comment: Why limit this to one parent? If you have three forms that use this behaviour across several pages, this fixes all, instead of having to use three distinct selectors. Also, this will prevent unchecking any other checkboxes.